# Shell or bash in pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How do you disable shell or bash access to pods in a container? I do not want anyone to get access inside the pod via kubectl exec or docker exec or via k9s

Answer (score 2):

Kubectl is a CLI tool so it connects with the **K8s** **API server** and authenticates.

You can restrict the user by their Role, so using the **RBAC** with proper permission will resolve your issue.

Ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

**Example** :

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: serviceaccount
  namespace: default

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: default-user-role
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - pods/attach
  - pods/exec
  verbs: [""]
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: default-user-view
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: serviceaccount
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: default-user-role
```

check auth using the

```
kubectl auth can-i --as=system:serviceaccount:default:serviceaccount exec pod
```